# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with different sources

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to show my current value and list options from different data sources.
Such, current item in the combobox is from SelectedData and the list of options when I click on the combobox is from ListOfData source. Is there a way to accomplish this? I even tried with DataGridComboBoxColumn but did not work out. Thanks.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedData}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>               
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dev-Code" Binding="{Binding ageCode}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDName" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ageName }" IsReadOnly="False"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding ageName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectedValuePath="ageNameId"/>  
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why don't you use IValueConverter for that purpose (to get another data source), and create a separate template for selected item

Comment: Where is `SelectedData` defined? What is your VM?